# How to repeat a Spring model in a Thymeleaf fragment

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring + Thymeleaf project. I have a fragment for the header part and some pages which include the header.

Below is the (essential part of) the header fragment. As you can see it includes the `activeUserWorkgroup` model object

`dashboard-header.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<body>
    <header th:fragment="dashboard-header" class="header">
    ....
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                            <span class="user-label" style="margin-left:5px;" 
                                  th:text="${activeUserWorkgroup.getWorkgroupLabel()}">
                            </span>
                        </a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

In every Spring view where I need the header fragment I add the line

```
<div th:replace="fragments/dashboard-header :: dashboard-header"></div>
```

The problem is that in every Controller of every View in which I need this header, I have to give the proper value to the `activeUserWorkgroup` model object. This is both uncomfortable and error prone.

Is there any way to let Spring give the proper model value to the `activeUserWorkgroup` object without having to write the code in every Controller?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is better to create a ControllerAdvice, read the documentation at this link [http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html](http://docs)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ModelAttribute("activeUserWorkgroup ")
    public String getActiveWorkgroup() {    
       //YOUR CODE
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This probably what you are looking for. What I would do is create controller that return just the Model object `activeUseWorkgroup`. Then have all the other controllers extend it.

```
@Controller
public ControllerA
{
     @ModelAttribute("activeUserWorkgroup")
     public Object getActiveUserWorkgroup()
     {
         return new Object();
     }
}

@Controller
public ControllerB extends ControllerA
{
}
```